# Mysql giving randomly count rows bad result when table having huge numbers of rows

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a `mysql` table (innoDb) having 7100000+ rows in it, my problem is when I open my `DB` it displays total number of rows count in some randomly manner, for ex. `~6,802,003` , `~6,906,828` , `~6,953,417`, `~7,034,948` ... and all. How can i get exact number of rows count of that table

Ex. [image]

[image]

Comment: How you are getting count...It seems very frequent insertion is being done in table due to this reason numbers are showing in increasing mode.....what is your problem please eleborate.

Comment: I havnt downvoted you, but never heard of Lakhs - however [wikipedia has a good reference for it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh). I think you should replace it with 7.1 millions+

Comment: Please, check [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-doesnt-innodb-store-the-row-count) answers

Comment: InnoDB does not store an exact count. The only way to get the real count is to `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: `~` means an approximation. But however, try with `select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  x from table limit 1` and then executing `select found_rows()` should return you total number, with no approximation, of rows in the table.